# CakePHP v2.6 and BotDetect Captcha

Tags: cakephp, captcha

I'm using BotDetect Captcha in a CakePHP 2.6 application, and have implemented it as per the instructions on this page:

[How To Add BotDetect Protection To CakePHP 2.6 Applications](https://captcha.com/doc/php/howto/cakephp-2.6-captcha.html)

The Captcha is working great on the controller/view where I need it.

However, it seems to be interfering somehow with the standard login process used by the same controller.

Here's my header for the controller which loads the BotDetect Component:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler','Epd','BotDetect.Captcha' => array(
                'CaptchaId' => 'EpdCaptcha',
                'UserInputId' => 'CaptchaCode'));
```

Here's my login function:

```
public function login() {
    $this->layout='login';
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

And here's my AppController.php:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'selectorg'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                )
            )
        ),
        'Session'
    );}
```

Now when I login to the app, the auth component isn't authorizing the login, and it's just bouncing back to the login screen.  But when I remove the BotDetect component, the login works perfectly. I've tried changing the order of loading Components to see if that makes any difference... but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to integrate BotDetect Captcha component in cakephp 2.6 and it's working ok for me.

Controller: UsersController.php:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array(
        'RequestHandler',
        'BotDetect.Captcha' => array(
            'CaptchaId' => 'EpdCaptcha',
            'UserInputId' => 'CaptchaCode'
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('logout');
        $this->Security->validatePost = false;
    }

    public function selectorg() {
        echo 'selectorg';
        $this->autoRender = false;
    }

    public function login() {

        $this->set('captchaHtml', $this->Captcha->Html());

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $isHuman = $this->Captcha->Validate($this->request->data['User']['CaptchaCode']);

            unset($this->request->data['User']['CaptchaCode']);

            if ($isHuman && $this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            } else {
                if (!$isHuman) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('CAPTCHA validation failed, try again.'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public function logout() {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

}
```

Controller: AppController.php:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Security',
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'selectorg'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array('Form' => array('passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'))
        )
    );

}
```

View: login.ctp

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->css(CaptchaUrls::LayoutStylesheetUrl(), array('inline' => false));

    echo $this->Form->create('User');

    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');

    echo $this->Html->div('captcha', $captchaHtml, false);

    // Captcha code user input textbox
    echo $this->Form->input('CaptchaCode', array(
            'label' => 'Retype the characters from the picture:',
            'maxlength' => '10',
            'style' => 'width: 300px;'
        )
    );

    echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

Model: User.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';

    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter your username'
            ),
            'unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'Username already exists'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter your password'
            )
        )
    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```